# Series Connected Secondary Transformer

Tags: transformer, series, winding

I have a multiple-winding transformer with the following configuration:

- primary: 230V
- secondary: 2x 10-12-15V
- frequency: 50Hz
- power : 66VA
- current: 2x 2.2A

[image: 66VA-2A2 transformer]

As far as I can understand from its specs the connection should be done like this:

- the primary coil should be connected to the main's AC by using the pair 4-7
- for the secondary coils we can connect the pin as following:

  - to get a 10VAC we may use the pair 9-12 or pair 2-17
  - to get a 12VAC we may use the pair 9-13 or pair 2-18
  - to get a 15VAC we may use the pair 9-14 or pair 2-19

[image: multiple winding transformer]

I think it's obvious how to get a 10VAC or 2x10VAC from this transformer, right? The same apply for the 12/15 VAC outputs.

I know that in general we can connect these secondaries either in series or in parallel (thus increasing the secondary voltage or the current rate).

**So my questions are**:

1. I'm wondering if it's safe to assume that by connecting the pair 9-13 in series with 2-18 I could expect to get a 24VAC. The same for 9-14 with 2-19 which should give a 30VAC.
2. It is safe to assume that by connecting the pin 9 to 13 then 13 to pin 2 I would get a 24VAC between pins 9-18 ?

Assuming that the both questions above would get a YES answer, what else should I know before doing that? Any tips?

Comment: You should trust your multimeter when connecting two windings in series. If you can measure 12 V AC between point 9 and 13 as well as between 2 and 18 and 24 V for both windings in series you connected the windings in the right order. If you measure a voltage lower than some 1 V for the series connection, you just have to reverse one winding. If you connect point 13 to point 2 and you measure 24 V between points 9 and 18, all is well. If you measure a much lower voltage between point 9 and 18, try to connect point 13 to point 18 and measure between point 9 and 2.

Comment: Yes, I already did that after Andy's answer. I can confirm that the 20-24-30VAC outputs obtained by series connecting the alike winding work. Obviously it would work also by connecting different tap points like 10V-12V  to get a 22VAC or a 12V-15V to get a 24VAC, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if it's safe to assume that by connecting the pair 9-13
>   in series with 2-18 I could expect to get a 24VAC. The same for 9-14
>   with 2-19 which should give a 30VAC.

I think it's a safe bet that if you series connected the windings you get twice the voltage so, for instance 9-13 in series with 2-18 would give you 24 V AC. Ditto for 9-14 and 2-19 to give 30 V AC.

> It is safe to assume that by connecting the pin 9 to 13 then 13 to pin
>   2 I would get a 24VAC between pins 9-18 ?

You cannot connect pin 9 to pin 13 under any circumstances (unless you want to burn out a winding).

Comment: You have right, by connection 9 to 13 the respective winding would be a short circuit. My HUGE mistake. Thanks for pointing this out. The correct path would be 9-13-2-18 which would mean to connect 13-2 and measure the output between 9-18. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that would be correct and is the right way to go - plenty of folk do this with dual output secondaries.

Comment: Now what if I want to get both, a 24VAC (by series connecting the 12-12VAC secondaries) and a 30VAC (by series connecting the 15-15VAC secondaries) at the same time? Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible with the transformer you have unless the common link between the two secondaries was from pin 9 to pin 2 (as opposed to pin 14 to pin 2). The label gives a strong indication that the common link is from 14 to 2 but, if you can dig-up a data sheet for it then it might say things differently.

Comment: The datasheet doesn't say much (at least not to me): https://goo.gl/kVujkV

Comment: I was thinking (although I don't know if it's right nor if if would theoretically work) that by connecting furthermore the 9-19 I could get 30VAC between 2-14. So the first connection (24VAC is as shown above) and the 30VAC would be like the one mentioned here. I draw a sketch and I see no conflict (a short path) but honestly I have no idea if it would work or if the output would be the expected one.

Comment: Yeah I found that data sheet from the 514780 number in your picture and yes, there is no clue. It wouldn't hurt to try it though. Just make sure you have only one cross connection between the two secondaries and get measuring some voltages relative to that cross-connection.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your suggestion. Can you be little bit more detailed?

Comment: Make the link between the two secondaries and check what voltages appear on all the other secondary pins. I originally said check voltages relative to the link i.e. use that as 0 volts but I'm going to change my mind to to check voltages from the end connection of one of the secondaries to all the other secondary pins.

Comment: OK, so after connecting 2-12 I measured all possible voltages (16 pairs) and I've got voltages as: 0,2,5,7,8,10,12,13,15,20,22,25 VAC. Started again but this time by connecting 9-19: 0,2,5,10,12,15,17,18,20,25,28,30. It looks like this connection provides the most of the searched voltages: 10,25,30. Now, depending if the measured ends belonged to the same secondary or to different series connected secondaries, the resulted voltage allows either 2.2A or 4.4A (not measured but theoretically that's how it is supposed to work).

Comment: Importantly, you have a connection at 15 volts that becomes the new 0 volts for the power supply but one more thing, make sure that you can measure 20 volts across the 5 and 25 positions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59740/discussion-between-eugen-mihailescu-and-andy-aka).